# Android reloading intent data on returning to activity from activity group

Tags: android, activitygroup

I have multiple tabs and within them I have got an activity group for each. When I go from one tab to another then hit back I lose my intent data.

For example, I start activity 1, pass object 1 to activity 2 via the activitygroup I then go to activity 3 passing object 1, however when I go back to activity 2 onCreate is never called and I cannot set my intent data if I want to go back to Activity 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send data between activities you can use `startActivitiForResult` or you can do something like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, Activiti2.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(intent);
```

in Activity2 :

```
String getData = getIntent().getStringExtra("key","default value");
// or getParent().getIntent().getStringExtra("key","default value"); depending on your situation.
```

and if you want to send data to Activity from Activity2 you can do something like this :

```
 Intent intent = getParent().getIntent();
 intent.putExtra("key", 0); // default sorting
 getParent().setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
 finish();
```

Comment: I think that might work, its for the situation when i go back to the original calling intent and rather than reloading the data from a webservice i would like to just pass the original data back.

Comment: I'm using this when I need to add some extra integers to my sql statement to the main activity from it's child and it's working as I need. So I think it have to work in your situation too.